# React JS : this.setState and JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native, react-router

I have a problem, I don't know how I can fix it. I am doint a request to my api and it responds with an object like this :

```
{"_id":"5a806648300caf0072c7254a","mail":"email@email.com"}
```

I want to print to my react component the mail. In my "componentDidMount()" function I get the mail, so there is no problem with my api. But when I want to set the state of my "users" variable, I can not print the variable in my component... It says that it's undefined.

Here is my code :

```
class UserList extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {users:[]}
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        //here my function that store the response from my api
        GetData('http://localhost:3333/users', 'username=admin', 
        (res) => 
        {
            this.setState({users: JSON.parse(res)});
            //Here I can log the mail
            console.log(this.state.users[0].mail);
        })
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <table>
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>EMAIL</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        //Here it is 'undefined'
                        <td>{this.state.users[0].mail}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        );
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React mounting component lifecycle is:

- constructor
- componentWillMount
- render
- componentDidMount

See more here: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#mounting

When your component is mounting this.state.users is an empty array.

You can change the render method:

```js
class UserList extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {users:[]}
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        //here my function that store the response from my api
        GetData('http://localhost:3333/users', 'username=admin', 
        (res) => 
        {
            // After setState react runs updating lifecycle methods (https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#updating)
            this.setState({users: JSON.parse(res)});
            //Here I can log the mail
            console.log(this.state.users[0].mail);
        })
    }
    render() {
        // if users are not loaded, we return null from render function
        if (this.state.users.length === 0) {
            return null;
        }
        
        return (
            <table>
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>EMAIL</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>{this.state.users[0].mail}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: How i do it with  fetch?

Comment: @SupunAbesekara you can just replace GetData with window.fetch and use promise chaining e.g.: `window.fetch(url, data).then(result => result.json()).then(json => this.setState({users: json.users});`

Answer (score 0):

You should not directly use the values from an asynchronous action.

As the `GetData` in componentDidMount() is asynchronous function, it will take some time to get data. So in the initial render the `user` in state is empty.

It is better to use loading indicator untill the data is fetched and show the data only when the data is received.

You may use as below.

```
class UserList extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {users:[]},
        loading: false
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        //here my function that store the response from my api
        this.setState({loading: true});
        GetData('http://localhost:3333/users', 'username=admin', 
        (res) => 
        {
            this.setState({users: JSON.parse(res), loading: false});
            //Here I can log the mail
            console.log(this.state.users[0].mail);
        })
    }
    render() {
        if(this.state.loading){
            return (<div> Loading... </div>)
        }
        return (
           <div>
            <table>
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>EMAIL</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                   {this.state.users.length > 0 &&
                    <tr>

                      <td>{this.state.users[0].mail || ''}</td>

                    </tr>
                   }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        );
    }
}
```

use may use map to loop as below

```
               {this.state.users.length > 0 && this.state.users.map(user => 
               return(
                    <tr>

                      <td>{user.mail || ''}</td>

                    </tr>)
                   }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the above case, the problem is with understanding Component Lifecycle of React.

Please take a look at the [reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#mounting).

ComponentDidMount occurs after the render has occurred.

Hierarchy will be 1. constructor 2. componentWillMount 3. render 4. componentDidMount

if the code is modified with replacing ComponentDidMount with ComponentWillMount

```
componentWillMount() {
     //here my function that store the response from my api
        GetData('http://localhost:3333/users', 'username=admin', 
        (res) => 
        {
            this.setState({users: JSON.parse(res)});
            //Here I can log the mail
            console.log(this.state.users.mail);
        })
  }
```

if the api is working correctly it will give the data.

But wait as the response from the api is an object and initializing the state with an array is also conceptually not correct I think so.

As I work most of project in Typescript, initialization of state is important to me.

```
constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {users:{
                         mail: ''
                      }}
}
```

Personal preference is the checking the user state is undefined or not this will surely not allow you to lead any undefined or errors.